# Error message when subquerying to get MAX value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this select statement:

```
SELECT
    l.rowno, 
    MAX(a.beac) AS AppBeacon,
    l.beac AS LoanBeacon
FROM 
    l
LEFT JOIN 
    a ON a.rowno = l.rowno
GROUP BY 
    l.rowno, l.beac
HAVING 
    rowno = l.rowno
ORDER BY
    l.rowno;
```

This results in this output

[image]

What I am trying to do is combine the AppBeacon and LoanBeacon into 1 column. My criteria is if LoanBeacon is <=1 then use AppBeacon as long as AppBeacon is not null, otherwise use LoanBeacon.

Through looking at other questions here I tried a subquery and came up with this query

```
SELECT
    l.rowno,
    CASE
        WHEN l.beac <= 1 
           THEN (SELECT MAX(a.beac) 
                 FROM l
                 LEFT JOIN a ON a.rowno = l.rowno
                 GROUP BY rowno, loan.beacon
                 HAVING rowno = loan.rowno)
           ELSE loan.beacon
    END as BeaconFinal
FROM 
    l 
LEFT JOIN 
    a ON a.rowno = l.rowno
ORDER BY
    rowno;
```

This results in this error message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Not really sure where to go from here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first query should be returning an error because `rowno` in the `select` is ambiguous.

Comment: my bad, missed that when I copied it over to here -- I've edited the query here

Comment: @tdm i think source data and expected output will be helpful to guide accurate path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this should work...

```
select 
    rowno
    ,NewColumn = max(case when LoanBeacon <= 1 then coalesce(AppBeacon, LoanBeacon) else LoanBeacon end )
FROM 
    l
LEFT JOIN 
    a ON a.rowno = l.rowno
GROUP BY 
    l.rowno
ORDER BY
    l.rowno;
```

Comment: thank you this does create the combined column properly, but now it is ignoring my original MAX(a.beacon) and I have multiple rows per rowno because it is showing all of the a.beacon values instead of just the MAX per rowno

Comment: I am not following your comment, but perhaps because the sample data is so limited. Sorry. This wouldn't have multiple multiple rows per rowno since we are grouping by rowno.

Comment: your second query worked for me -- still not sure why the first one wasn't. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT l.rowno, 
       MAX(a.beac) AS AppBeacon,
       l.beac AS LoanBeacon,
       (CASE WHEN l.beac <= 1 THEN MAX(a.beac) ELSE l.beac END) as combined_column
FROM l LEFT JOIN
     a
     ON a.rowno = l.rowno
GROUP BY l.rowno, l.beac
ORDER BY l.rowno;
```

The `HAVING` clause is not doing anything useful, so I removed it.

Comment: that works in that it makes my combined column, but now instead of showing me just the MAX(a.beac) I have a row for every a.beac per rowno. So now I have multiple rows per rowno if there was more than one a.beac for that rowno. I just want the highest value

Comment: @tdm . . . This is *your query* with the addition of a `CASE` expression.  It should be returning the same rows as your original query.

Comment: I definitely agree with you that it should. I will edit my question to add this new code I've tried and show my output

Comment: @tdm just to check, is `rownum` declared unique on the `l` table?

Comment: @JohnLBevan yes it is

Comment: @tdm . . . Based on your question and your data, it makes no sense that this does not work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the accepted answer works for me -- maybe because the MAX is outside the CASE instead of inside it?

Comment: @tdm . . . I'm not sure that it is actually the logic you describe.